# Regex: Replacing single quotes but taking care of apostrophes

Tags: regex

(I am certain that this question has already been asked, but I cannot find it.)

I need to replace anything between single quotes with `\enquote{}`, the capture to be put inside the curly brackets. With double quotes I can get away with:

- FIND: `"(.*?)"`
- REPLACE: `\\enquote{$1}`

But with single quotes there is the obvious problem of apostrophes. Is there way to solve that problem.

Example:

```
He said, 'it's always sunny here.'
```

Comment: You might get better answers if you define the environment where you're attempting this (TeX?).

Comment: @Hannu Thanks for your comment. Does that really matter? Yes, I have `LaTeX` in mind, but the answer may be helpful in other contexts.

Comment: What options there are in LaTeX might steer the answer away from complexity, or not (I have very little TeX experience).

Comment: This is almost impossible to automate, because apostrophes can start a word, for example with `‘70s` as an abbreviation for 1970s. And so you might have a sentence like: `I said ‘I was born in the ‘70s’`.

Answer (score 1):

One multi-step approach:

1. Use Search and Replace, "replace all" to replace `space+'` with
   something appropriate (e.g. space+")
2. repeat .1 for `'+space`.
3. you might also have `'.` to handle...
   (i.e. `'` at the end of a sentence, and also at the end of a line -
   and how about at the very beginning of a line?)
4. Now use Search and Replace to replace `'` into `"` for
   the remaining instances and select to replace or not, manually (Yes/No).

To get this to work with an automated process?
That is a bit harder to say the least, I'm all ears regarding that...

If you can find a way to express the Search-items above with regex'es (i.e. `$ man re_format`) then you might be at least part of the way to automation.
This https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html might be of some help there though, but I take it that `\b` isn't available in all regex-implementations.

Answer (score 1):

As you didn't give the language/tool you are using, I give a solution that uses Notepad++.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\w'\w(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|'(.+?)'(?!\w)`
- Replace with: `\\enquote{$1}`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **CHECK** `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
  \w            # 1 word character
  '             # single quote (in fact an apostrophe)
  \w            # 1 word character
  (*SKIP)       # skip this match
  (*FAIL)       # abort this match (don't considere the apostrophe)
|               # OR
  '             # single quote
  (.+?)         # group 1, 1 or more any character, not greedy
  '             # single quote
  (?!\w)        # only if not followed by a word character
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]